# Borrar datos de Firebase Android dentro de un nodo

Tags: android, firebase, recyclerview

llevo poco programando en Android y tengo problemas al intentar borrar el un registro de mi base de datos en Firebase. Para borrar los datos estoy usando el método onSwiped dentro de un RecyclerView. 
Ahora mismo el problema lo que hago es borrar todo el registro que tengo dentro del nodo padre, y me borra toda la información que el usuario guarda dentro de tabernas favoritas, y no la celda que ha sido eliminada con el método onSwiped.

He visto algún ejemplo similar, pero no me funciona y me sigue borrando toda la información

Este es mi Fragment donde borro los datos de la lista y de Firebase

```
private void deleteFavoritesTavern() {
        new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

@Override
public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            favoriteTavernList.remove(position);

            adapterFavoritas.notifyItemRemoved(position);

            Query mQuery = databaseListaTabernasFavoritas.child("tabernasfavoritas");
            mQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        favoriteTavernList.clear();
                       ds.getRef().removeValue();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerViewFavoritas);
}
```

Quiero borrar solo esta:

[image: Datos de la Firebase Database]

Gracias.

Comment: Hola Manuel; Entiendo que quieres eliminarlos de la BD, y no del snapshot, verdad?¿?

Comment: Hola Alejandro, exacto, quiero eleminarlo de la BD

Comment: Hola @Manuel, entonces tu pregunta debería considerarse como duplicada dentro de Stackoverflow. Voy a marcarla inicialmente ya que también es desde Android. Echa un vistazo a esa. En tu caso, estás eliminando el objeto del Snapshot, pero no de la BD. Revisa la pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/174890/como-eliminar-un-registro-de-firebase-desde-android-studio

Comment: Estuve viendo el ejemplo que me indicas, y me borra todo el registro y no solo en la que haces el evento de eliminar.

Comment: cómo todo el registro? Te refieres a la lista completa?

Comment: Exacto, en vez de borrar solo un registro, me borra todos los registros que haya dentro de el.

Comment: Has filtrado por el ID???

Comment: No, cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Creo que lo estás haciendo bien, pero te sobra el `favoriteTavernList.clear();`

Ya estás eliminando en teoría con `ds.getRef().removeValue();`

Comment: De esa forma ya lo había probado, y si borro un registro, pero se borrar el primer registro de la BD, aunque en la lista elimine el que se encuentra en la posición 3 por ejemplo.

Comment: Deberías obtener el ID del objeto que has metido en la posición asociada al que has hecho el swipe. Entiendo que lo tienes en favoriteTavernList.get(position).key o similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es el siguiente, cuando vas a la referencia para borrar, vas directamente a todo el nodo `tabernasFavoritas` y no directamente al id dentro de tabernasFavoritas que quieres borrar.

En esta linea

```
Query mQuery = databaseListaTabernasFavoritas.child("tabernasfavoritas")
```

debes incluir un child mas que seria el objeto que quieres borrar dentro de `tabernasFavoritas`.

Simplemente podes hacer

```
databaseListaTabernasFavoritas.child("tabernasfavoritas").child(KEY).removeValue()
```

Para probar que esto funciona, pon en KEY el valor de la KEY que quieres borrar en firebase como hardcodeada, una vez que hagas el swipe veras que esa key se borra dentro de tu nodo `tabernasFavoritas`

Ahora, lo que deberias hacer para saber cual id borrar de Firebase al borrar ese objeto de la lista es lo siguiente.

Cuando obtenes el objeto de la lista a borrar con

```
int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            favoriteTavernList.remove(position);
```

Lo que podes hacer es en el momento que traes el valor de este objeto es almacenar en ese objeto tambien el ID que le corresponde al momento de ser creado, entonces luego solo accedes al id del objeto que estas por borrar para borrarlo tambien de Firebase

```
int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            favoriteTavernList.remove(position);
String key = favoriteTavernList.get(position).tabernaID;
```

y luego

```
databaseListaTabernasFavoritas.child("tabernasfavoritas").child(tabernaId).removeValue()
```

Entonces cuando haces swipe de ese elemento, ya el mismo objeto almacena el id en Firebase en donde hacer referencia, y solo vas a ese ID dentro de tabernasfavoritas y borras ese elemento.

Comment: Buenos días, esta tarde cuando llegue a casa prueba lo que me dices para ver si funciona. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Gastón, lo acabo de probar (ayer no pude), y funciona sin problema!!! Te marco la respuesta como válida. Muchas gracias.